# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass NoMethodError in Projects#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a project management system and each project have its progress status but making the category show in my new page isn't working

but i receive `` undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass ``

this is my project controller

```
def new
    @project = Project.new 
    @progresses = Progress.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end
```

and my project/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= select_tag(:progress_id, options_for_select(@progressess), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
  </div>
```

models/progress.rb

```
has_many :projects
```

models/project.rb

```
belongs_to :progress
```

i want the progress to show on the project form as a dropdown so i can select in it

Comment: i receive ```undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass```, how do i fix the error

Comment: I guess the answer below nailed it down. @albert: can you mark the answer as accepted, so that it gets filtered?

Comment: i'm a new user, i dont have enough reputation to mark corrent answers yet

Comment: Thanks for the update, did not remember that fact, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've mistyped `progresses` in  .erb file

Comment: One of the downsides of using instance variables to pass data around :-)